# Negative lookahead in strsplit puzzling behaviour

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I am confused by a simple lookahead behaviour in strsplit in R v3.6.2: when I try to match a space () *not* followed by a forward-slash (`/`) the regex behaves oddly.

The below attempt correctly doesn't consume the forward-slash but still splits at the space afterwards. The output is the same with patterns: `' (?!/ )'` and `' (?!/ *)'`, also with other wildcards `.` and `?`.

```
strsplit(c("foo1 foo2", "foo1 / foo2", "foo1/foo2"), ' (?!/)', perl = T)
[[1]]
[1] "foo1" "foo2"

[[2]]
[1] "foo1 /" "foo2"  

[[3]]
[1] "foo1/foo2"
```

This is all the more confusing because if I negate a positive lookahead, strsplit simply won't split anything. This persists with different patterns as above.

```
strsplit(c("foo1 foo2", "foo1 / foo2", "foo1/foo2"), ' ^(?=/)', perl = T)
[[1]]
[1] "foo1 foo2"

[[2]]
[1] "foo1 / foo2"

[[3]]
[1] "foo1/foo2"
```

Escaping the forward-slash (that shouldn't be a special character anyways) yields the same results.

The desired output should look like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "foo1" "foo2"

[[2]]
[1] "foo1 / foo2"  

[[3]]
[1] "foo1/foo2"
```

Apologies if this is very basic, but I couldn't find an explanation for this specific behaviour.

Comment: You are not negating the pattern anywhere. `' ^(?=/)'` is a pattern that never matches anything as the `^` - start of string - cannot appear after a space.

Comment: Can you specify why you believe `"foo1 / foo2"` --> `"foo1 /" "foo2" ` is not what you are asking for? The space after the slash is not followed by a slash.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for the quick reply. Indeed I made a mistake in negating the positive lookahead. Still, I don't understand why the negative looakahead `' (?!/)'` doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: @Luca I added more explanations and "solutions" to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [original regex](https://regex101.com/r/KN73pN/2) does not work for you because the spaces *after* `/` are still matched.  `(?!/)` matches any space that is not directly followed with a `/`, but not if it is preceded with `/`.

You might try `(?<!/) (?!/)` - see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KN73pN/3), but this will still match on spaces that are before  `/` or after `/` .

In order to match any 1+ whitespace chars but the cases when the whitespaces enclose a `/` char, you may use

```
strsplit(c("foo1 foo2", "foo1 / foo2", "foo1/foo2"), '\\s*/\\s*(*SKIP)(*F)|\\s+', perl=TRUE)
```

The `\s*/\s*(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+` (see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/KN73pN/1)) pattern matches

- `\s*/\s*(*SKIP)(*F)`  - consumes 1+ whitespaces, `/` and then 1+ whitespaces and discards the match
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - consumes 1+ whitespaces

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I was not aware of the SKIP and F operators in regex.

Comment: @Luca That is the most generic pattern. Note that `(?<!/) (?!/)` [will still fail](https://regex101.com/r/KN73pN/4) in edge cases (see the bottom tests)